# How to build a payment system as Airbnb with Stripe and Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments

I need your help. I'm building a website similar to Airbnb containing the following tool:

- Hivepress template
- Woocommerce
- Stripe plugin for payments called "Payment Plugins for Stripe
  WooCommerce" (Payments works with Stripe Connect express) Hotel has
  to register on "connect" before creating a listing.
- Stripe plugin customization to collect FEES

I'm using Stripe Connect express but I think I missed something due I paid the final user (hotel) straight away.

I want to achieve that result:

- The user book a hotel (paying total + commission 15%)
- My site receives the booking confirmation
- 24h after the booking I pay the hotel (money has to get directly from
  the user who pays and not from my balance)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating separate charges and transfers, you need to specify the `source_transaction` parameter to tie a transfer to an existing charge. You can read more about this [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges-transfers#transfer-availability).

Comment: Thanks for your info.                                              
                                                                               
- We want to transfer the payment to the hotel ONLY once the Credit Card charge has been processed to avoid the amount being taken from our balance.

- We would like to release the payment ONLY 24h after the check-in as you mentioned.